# Why, in this example, is the Hoare partition algorithm not returning correct pivot index position?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

Let say I have the following array :

```
3, 6, 9, 1, 4
```

I want to partition it around a pivot, using Hoare algorithm :

```
Hoare-Partition (A, p, r)
    x ← A[p]
    i ← p − 1
    j ← r + 1
    while  TRUE
        repeat   j ←  j − 1
            until     A[j] ≤ x
        repeat   i ←  i + 1
            until     A[i] ≥ x
        if  i < j
            exchange  A[i] ↔ A[j]
        else  return   j
```

I have chose the number in the middle (9) to be the pivot.
Here is the algorithm applied, step by step :

```
3, 6, 9, 1, 4
i           j //increase i, decrease j

3, 6, 9, 1, 4
      i     j //exchange 4 and 9

3, 6, 4, 1, 9
      i     j //increase i, decrease j 

3, 6, 4, 1, 9
         j  i //i > j, stop
```

Array is correctly partitioned around pivot, however, pivot index value returned is 3 while I expected it to be 4.

Comment: Are you assuming zero-base or one-based indexing?

Comment: when you apply the algorithm what are the parameters used? (p,q=?)

Comment: This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) vaguely mentions that the return value is 'the final index', which apparently is the index of the left boundary. Assuming zero-based indexing, that would be correct in your example.

Comment: I am assuming zero-base indexing. Parameters are p = 0, q = 4

Comment: Why did you expect it to be 4? With zero-base indexing and the parameters you saym it will clearly be 3. Also note that if your array content had been, say, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, j would have gone off the array to the left in the second iteration of the while-true loop.